# Semiconductor switching device with extremely low leakage current in off state

Tags: switches, semiconductors

I would like to use a semiconductor device that acts like an ideal relay, that is, with very low leakage current in the off state. By very low, I mean at least 100 pA per volt (like a 10GOhm resistor), and preferably 10pA per volt. Relays are good but they use too much current for my application. I don't think that the Mosfets I know do that. Any idea?

EDIT (for my particular application):

- supply voltage: preferably 3V, may be 5V
- switching frequency range: I need only very low frequencies 20-500 Hz is a good range
- current to switch: at most 1A, probably much less
- voltage to switch: very low, between 0.1V and 10V
- resistance in the on state: may be relatively high, even 1kOhm is probably good.

Comment: Latching relay maybe?

Comment: Achh good! I haven't think about that. I would prefer a semiconductor solution still.

Comment: What supply voltages do you have? What current is it switching? What on-resistance? What signal amplitudes? What frequency range? What switching speed? What temperature range?

Comment: OK, I'll edit my question.

Comment: I wouldn't discount mosfets just yet, for example AQ222R1S or AQ225R1S could be useful, but desired leakage current (50 pA or 30 pA) for them is only typical, maximum is over your desired value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible candidate might be an analogue switch such as the [ADG601/602](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG601_602.pdf): -

[image]

It has an on-resistance of 2.5 ohms and a leakage typically of 10 pA at 25 degC.

> *current to switch: at most 1A, probably much less*

Well, 1 amp would be fatal to the ADG60x because it has an on-resistance of 2.5 ohms but, you say later on this: -

> *resistance in the on state: may be relatively high, even 1kOhm is
>   probably good*

And if 1 amp passed through 1 kohm it would dissipate 1000 watts so you need to consider what you might *really* need.

But you also say this: -

> *voltage to switch: very low, between 0.1V and 10V*

And, to be able to use an analogue switch, it requires that the voltage supply exceeds the signal levels, so maybe the [ADG1201](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG1201.pdf) might be more suitable for this voltage range. It can operate from much larger supply rails (+/- 15 volts or +12 volts) but has an on-resistance of typically 120 ohm.

<sub>The ADG601/602 can operate from dual 5 volt rails but only a single positive rail of 5 volts. However, you might be able to bias it up to get a 10 volt operating range.</sub>

Food for thought.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Andy. I should have given more details about what I'm trying to do (but I have bad experience of giving too much details in this forum). Actually, I plan to make an Electrostatic field meter of my invention suitable to my research needs. The switch is supposed to short a cap of few pF, charged at few volts by the electrostatic field. Then the discharge is collected and measured. So, no real problem of big current here (I suppose).

Comment: OK, sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

If low leakage and GOhm impedance is a prime concern, then I would not recommend CMOS switches, even if some are rated with quite low leakage currents. Moreover, for your application of switching caps in the pF range, the charge injection and switch capacitance are serious concern.

If you really don't want to use relays, check Optically isolated MOS switches. They can be found with much better leakage than nonisolated CMOS switches. E.g. this part from Toshiba: TLP3450(TP,F

Also output capacitance for this switch is e.g. only around 1 pF

[image: TLP3450(TP,F off leakage]